# How can I fix overflow error when numbers can be too big?

Tags: java, double, long-integer, median

How can I fix the overflow error in the below method?

```
  public static double median(long[] numbers) {
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    int middle = numbers.length / 2;
    if (numbers.length % 2 == 1) {
      return numbers[middle];
    } else {
      return (numbers[middle - 1] + numbers[middle]) / 2.0;
    }
  }
```

This line  may overflow if the two numbers are too big:

```
return (numbers[middle - 1] + numbers[middle]) / 2.0;
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Add code to check that they don't overflow, and if they do, do something about it. There isn't much you can do with an overflowing `long` other than not use `long`s and instead use a `BigInteger`

Comment: `BigDecimal` can help you.

Comment: It's integer data

Comment: You could do: numbers[middle - 1] + (numbers[middle] - numbers[middle - 1]) / 2;

Comment: I don't think that's a dupe, @lexicore.  It's not necessary to *detect* or *predict* overflow, nor did the OP ask for that.  What he asked is how to avoid overflow happening in the first place.  That can be achieved in this case by rewriting the expression.

Comment: @EricS, the subtraction could also overflow if the array elements can be negative, but this won't: `numbers[middle - 1] / 2.0 + numbers[middle] / 2.0`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You are right.

Comment: @StackFlowed We've just decided it is not. :) Can be solved without risking overflow at all.

Comment: @lexicore oops my bad ... it does have a section on how to handle it.

Comment: @StackFlowed This is why I thought is is a duplicate and was corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This line may overflow if the two numbers are too big:
>
> ```
> return (numbers[middle - 1] + numbers[middle]) / 2.0;
> ```
>
> How to fix this?

The problem arises with the intermediate addition.  If you can rely on the elements of `numbers` to be non-negative, then you can perform the computation without risk of overflow like so:

```
return numbers[middle - 1] + (numbers[middle] - numbers[middle - 1]) / 2.0;
```

as @EricS mentioned in comments.

If you have to accommodate the full range of `long`, positive and negative, then you can do this:

```
return numbers[middle - 1] / 2.0 + numbers[middle] / 2.0;
```

Do be aware that `double` has greater range but less precision than `long`, in the sense of the number of significant digits each can represent.  If you really need to worry about `long` values at the extreme ends of that type's range, then you should have a think about what effect that precision loss will have on you.